# Where is the Custom Labels link in the Winter '16 release

Tags: customlabel

The Setup->Build->Create->Custom Labels link seems to be missing in the Winter'16 preview release.  Does anyone know where it went?  There's no mention of it changing in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be there. Prerelease orgs are not guaranteed to have all features enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response David.  I guess I was expecting that existing features not slated to deprecation/removal would still present in this pre-release.  Makes it kinda of tough to regression test functionality that depends on this feature. :-)  Will open a support case with SFDC to see if this is to be expected.  Regards.

Comment: Prerelease orgs are not intended, as far as I know, for ISV regression testing (though I may be wrong). I believe that sandboxes are better for that.
I could certainly be wrong on this - but then, myprerelease org is more "pre" than prerellogin.pre.salesforce.com, so I don't know what that pod would have as far as feature set.

Answer (score 0):

The new location is Setup > App Setup > Create > Custom Labels. Please find the below screenshot[image].

Comment: Thanks Saroj, but I'm not seeing anything called 'App Setup' under Setup.  Quick Search isn't returning anything for 'Custom Labels' either.